# What kind of distribution is my QQ-plot and histogram?

Tags: distributions, excel, histogram, qq-plot

I am pretty in new in distribution issues and I am trying to figure out what kind of distribution I have.

I have a historical data with more than 300 observations. I will calculate Value-at-Risk (VaR) and I was trying to see what kind of distribution the historical data has. I plotted QQ-plot and histogram on Excel (See the figures below).

I plotted the `Expectation` in the QQ-plot with Excel function `=Norm.Inv(CDF;Mean;StDev)`. `CDF` is Cumulative Distribution Function.

I plotted the `Real Data` as my sorted real data versus z-score. Z-score is calculated with the Excel function `=Norm.S.Inv(CDF)`

So what kind of distribution would be more suitable for this data?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your data certainly is not normal, maybe you could fit a mixture of normals to it.

Comment: I guess it is called polynormal distribution, right? I should search about it.

Comment: The kind of model you use depends on what you want to learn from that model.